# What is wrong with my CompositeDataBoundControl?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I have a CompositeDataBoundControl defined as below:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportSection.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebReports.ReportSection" %>
<div class="report-section span-24">
    <h3>
        <%= Title %></h3>
</div>

public partial class ReportSection : CompositeDataBoundControl
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    protected override int CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, bool dataBinding)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        return 1; // JUst something to avoid exceptions.
    }
}
```

Yet when I try and load a web form containing this control, I get the following parser error:

'WebReports.ReportSection' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

This seems very odd to me, because I get the impression that CompositeDataBoundControl is intended as a base class for user controls, or is it perhaps only for use with server controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is intended for server controls, not UserControls. UserControls are more similar to Pages than to other controls (both inherit from TemplatedControl).

You can see from the [MSDN description for CompositeDataBoundControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositedataboundcontrol.aspx) that it's not really intended for user controls:

> Represents the base class for a tabular data-bound control that is
>   composed of other server controls.